# How does one get dimens.xml (sw600dp) into Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I inherited the `values` folder structure shown below.

[image]

For over an hour I've Googled and looked and pulled down menus in Android Studio 1.2.2 and tried creating files and folders but nothing I have done lets me add, for instance, `dimens.xml (sw720dp)`.

I deleted `dimens.xml (sw720dp - landscape)` because `landscape` didn't suit my needs.

What steps did whoever created the folder structure take in order to get `dimens.xml (sw600dp)` to appear in the structure?

**What steps do I need to take to get a `dimens.xml` file with the `sw<N>dp` file naming convention? How do I get `dimens.xml (sw720dp)` where it belongs?**

You can ignore the rest of this. I'm just showing that I've TRIED stuff, none of which works right.

Am I supposed to right-click `values` or `dimens.xml (2)`? What then?

Here's what I did and it didn't do as I need:

[image]
[image]

I also tried:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

I also tried copying the `sw600dp` file. No luck:

[image]

IT CAN'T BE THIS HARD.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What steps do I need to take to get a dimens.xml file with the swdp file naming convention?

First, you will probably be happier with life if you change the drop-down above your project tree from "Android" to "Project", which shows you an actual filesystem view of your project.

To add a resource directory from within Android Studio:

1. Right-click over `res/`
2. Choose New > "Android resource directory" from the context menu to bring up the New Resource Directory dialog:

[image: Android Studio New Resource Directory]

3. Choose your resource type in the "Resource type" drop-down (in this case, `values`)
4. Click on your desired qualifier (in this case, "Smallest screen width") in the "Available qualifiers" list.
5. Click the >> button
6. In the field that appears, fill in your numeric value (in this case, 600)
7. Click OK to close the dialog and create the directory

To add `dimens.xml` to that directory, right-click over the newly-created directory and choose New > "Values resource file" from the context menu.

Comment: @Commonsware--I will thank you every time you hold my hand, even though at some point you might want to say, "Enough, already!" 

Good grief, I just for the first time noticed your gaudy rep value. Yikes.

Comment: @DSlomer64: "even though at some point you might want to say, "Enough, already!"" -- well, if you want [this sort of help in bulk form...](https://commonsware.com) :-)

Comment: @Commonsware--here's the hilarious part: I had JUST FOUND your 3300-page opus and was set to come back here and comment something like "HOLY SHNIKIES!" but you beat me to it. I am VERY interested in what I found.

Comment: > you will probably be happier with life if you change the drop-down above your project tree from "Android" to "Project", which shows you an actual filesystem view of your project.

zomg. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have had MANY failures trying to do stuff OUTSIDE Android Studio, but this time I got away with it:

[image]
[image]

I will now see how @Commonsware says I could have done it.

*EDIT*

And as always, @Commonsware bailed me out with good advice (I have no idea when or why or how I lost the `File structure` "tab" along the left margin).

Here's what I now see, and (I was right:) it's NOT hard to see what to do ONCE YOU SEE THIS:

[image]

And, following his advice, I get to here and am ready to create the `dimens.xml` file that goes inside:

[image]