# dimens.xml in Android doesn't work properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm encountering a problem with creating dimens.xml for different layouts:

My `dimens.xml` files:
[image: My dimens.xml files]

If I use these files, the layout won't work properly. I have tried this method with my Redmi 5 Plus phone and my layout was just broken.
But if I delete all of these folders and leave the original dimens.xml file out, the layout will work properly like before. What have I done wrongly?

After I've deleted the dimens.xml for different layouts:

[image: After I've deleted the dimens.xml for different layouts]

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684869/how-does-one-get-dimens-xml-sw600dp-into-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple library available in android to achieve different screen size screens.
Check the below library
[Sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

For text views please refer to ssp which is based on the sp size unit for texts.

for example:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
  // For TextView size
  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

In your layout file

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
```

Comment: I'm using dp for my textview size, is that okay?

Comment: Use ssp like below..Its recommended to use ssp for text sizes. Use  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6' for ssp

Comment: I have inserted these lines into my build.gradle file, so now how can I create dimens.xml for different layouts?