# How to add res/values-sw600dp file in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

i have activity_main.xml file in different size of the screen

```
activity_main.xml(land)  --> it auto generate the file layout-land
activity_main.xml(sw600dp) ---> it auto generate the file layout-sw600dp

BUT, it did not auto-generate the values-/res/values-sw600dp and /res/values-land
how to get this two file?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685049/7710739 you can check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right click in res folder
- new
- Android resource file
- change "value to layout" from resource type
- and click on "size" from available qualifiers
- then you choose

Comment: when i add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="screen_type">phone</string>
</resources>  it shows the error

Comment: you don't need to add screen_type. Just follow my answer then you fine. Just make sure that you name the same name for every screen size layout.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on the **Orientation for Preview** [icon looks like phone rotation] as shown in the image
- Select **Create Tablet Variation**
- [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoRfl.png)